# Is it possible to initiate new entries in Active Directory, or update existing entries in Active Directory, from SQL Server?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, windows, active-directory

I want some user fields to be updated in Active Directory from SQL server. Is it possible to do that or Is it possible to update the fields using python? Any pointers would be greatly helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like [Python LDAP](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/) to make changes in Active Directory via the LDAP interface. The challenge is knowing what/when data changes in your database table.

In MySQL, you can use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html) to perform actions when INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations are committed. A trigger could be used to populate a second table that is essentially a changelog. Either remove items from the changelog table when processed and updated into AD or maintain a "last change processed" number within your code and retain the changelog data as an audit log.